# Запрос с объединением двух записей одной таблицы

Tags: sqlite, база-данных

Допустим, есть таблица

```
create table X(id integer, name text)
```

и вторая таблица

```
create table Y(id1 integer, id2 integer)
```

Вторая как бы связывает две записи из первой таблицы.

Как мне одним запросом получить данные второй таблицы с такими столбцами:

```
|id1|name1|id2|name2|
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.id, t2.name from x as t1 inner join Y as t2 on t1.id=t2.id2
```

Вообще почитайте, что такое `inner/left/right join` - туториалов в Сети полно.

Comment: Спасибо, ну я уже искал, например, смотрел http://jtest.ru/bazyi-dannyix/sql-dlya-nachinayushhix-chast-3.html, но так и не догнал, как сделать то, что хочу, вот и решил спросить.

Comment: select x.id, x.name, y.id, y.id2 from x, y where y.id2 = x.id;

То же самое, но для объяснения(обучения) понятнее.

Comment: Запрос составлен неверно, выдает ошибки, а если вместо "t1.id, t1.name, t2.id, t2.name" указать "*", то выдает объединение таблиц X и Y, но мне это не нужно, мне нужны две записи из таблицы X в одном запросе.